# Using AFNetworking and getting Error 404

Tags: iphone, ios, phpmyadmin, xampp

Is my first attempt on this and I am facing the error

```
Expected status code in (200-299), got 404
```

I am following this tutorial > [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12)

and I have create the class below:

TalkToNetwork.h

```
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

typedef void (^JSONResponseBlock)(NSDictionary* json);

@interface TalkToNetwork : AFHTTPClient

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary* user;

-(BOOL)isAuthorized;

-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock;

+(TalkToNetwork*)sharedInst;

@end
```

TalkToNetwork.m

```
    #import "TalkToNetwork.h"

//the web location of the service
#define kAPIHost @"http://localhost/"
#define kAPIPath @"Test/"

@implementation TalkToNetwork

@synthesize user;

+(TalkToNetwork*)sharedInst{

    static TalkToNetwork *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];

    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(BOOL)isAuthorized{

    return [[user objectForKey:@"IdUser"] intValue] > 0;
}

-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock{

    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
    [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                    path:kAPIPath
                              parameters:params
               constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
               }];

    AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //success!
        printf("success");
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //failure :(
        printf("failure");
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];

    [operation start];
}


-(TalkToNetwork*)init{

    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        user = nil;

        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

I have downloaded and installed XAMPP as tutorial advice, running all three Controls (Apache, MySQL, FTP) and I have used `phpmyadmin` in order to create the database and a table ("login") manually.

I am following each step from the tutorial and still getting the error above. In addition, I'm passing manually the link to the browser "http://localhost/Test/" and getting Error 404. 
What I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a URL that is not valid. Check in your browser the URL ..

1. Check if Apache is running at `http//localhost/` or `http://172.0.0.1/` or.. `http://localhost:8080/`
2. Check if PHP is working well `http://localhost/test/index.php`
3. ...

**UPD**

from tutorial:

> "The extracted ZIP should contain a few PHP files and a folder named
>   “upload. The main API file is index.php"

... then.. "

> copy the files in Finder to your web folder"

...

> " you will have to change the domain and path if you have any setup
>   other than calling the API from your local machine"

Perhaps.. you must try `http://localhost/xampp/test/`

**UPD2**

Error 403 Access Forbidden:

**1** 
a)  In Finder select test folder
b)  Choose 'Show info'
c)  Under "Ownership & Permissions" check to have you read\write permission

**2**
check\modify your httpd.conf from "Deny from all" to "Order allow" and "Allow from all" - [like here](http://www.dclawson.com/2010/03/xampp-access-forbidden/)

Comment: Well, the localhost itself direct me to http://localhost/xampp/. I suppose you mean, http://127.0.0.1 and this direct me to the same page above. However, the php link returns "Object not found!". I am using a Mac machine, where it needs to has the index.php in order to find it? Thanks

Comment: Because I'm new owner of Mac machine .. do you know where I can find web folder? I am missing that point...

Comment: Update: Forgot to mention that I have already paste the folder with the files to WebServer/Documents in my HDD. I have tried localhost/~myusername/test, localhost/myusername/test, localhost/test,  localhost/xampp/~myusername/test with no success! I'm lost :(

Comment: /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ - The Apache DocumentRoot directory, this is where the webpages belong. Here.. you must put all folders\files..

Comment: OK, I have pasted the folder there. the URL http://localhost/xampp/test/index.php gives Error 404. However if I try http://localhost/test/index.php now giver Error 403 Access Forbidden! How I can fix it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: check the update.. P.S. restart the apache server after update

Comment: That's fix the problem THANK YOU! :) .. in addition, for others who facing the same problem, try localhost/~username/(or_the_name_of_the_folder_with_index.php)